# Detecting custom user actions in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

Is it possible to identify which **custom action button** has the user clicked on an Alfresco document library page? I would like to recognize this in java class and do some action or condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes me think about this tutorial : https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-action-doclib.html

You should be able to override existing actions and do whatever you like.